# How to stop Telegramm bot if terminal has been closed?

Tags: php, linux, terminal

I use PHP "[badfarm/zanzara](https://github.com/badfarm/zanzara)" Telegramm-bot. I had started it by terminal in browser on my Fornex hosting with command `php start_bot.php` which refers to script "start_bot.php" execution. After that I have closed terminal but the bot did not stop. It has been running several days by now. How could I stop the bot?

Here is an approximate code sample (it's more complicated in real script):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

0. Download and install `htop`
1. Start `htop` by the same command
2. Press F4 and input `php start_bot.php` then press ENTER
3. F9 and select SIGKILL
4. Done

Comment: There is no htop at my hosting and I'm pretty sure that there is no opportunity to get it. But thanks to your answer, I've solved my problem with ps.

Comment: @IvanShumakov are you using a dedicated server or VDS?